# Two-dimensional array of Lists

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I'm in the need of a two dimensional matrix of list, e.g. ArrayList, and I'm wondering what is most preferable in this case. It only needs to be 4x4 in size.

Should I use something like

```
    ArrayList[][] foo = new ArrayList[4][4];
```

or

```
    ArrayList<SomeClass>[][] foo = new ArrayList[4][4];
```

and initialize every element with the proper type in a for loop or

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<SomeClass>>> foo = ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<SomeClass>>>();
```

The first method generates warnings like it should be parametrized and if I add use the second I get unchecked conversion warnings. But if I loop over the elements and initialize them there should not be any problem even if I still get the warning? The last method does not generate any warnings and probably works fine but it feels kinda messy.

EDIT: Got some nice answers to my question even if it was a bit unclear. But it was basically how to make a table of Lists. Creating a custom class to handle rows/columns it made it a a lot easier.

Comment: The second method should read: `ArrayList<SomeClass>[][] foo = new ArrayList<SomeClass>[4][4];`, however having an array of lists seems somewhat awkward. Do you really need that 2-dimensional array? If so, could you provide some more information on why?

Comment: Having ArrayList<SomeClass>[][] foo = new ArrayList<SomeClass>[4][4]; Is produces the error "Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList<SomeClass>, that was why I left it out :)

Comment: And the reason why I need it is that I have a table containing "results". Depending on the result of an operation I want to add these objects to one of these lists in the 2D array. Does that make things clearer? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix the first method as following:

List[][] foo = new ArrayList[4][4];

The second method is not what you need. You are trying to create 4 dimensional array instead of 2 dimensional array 4*4 elements.

Additionally I'd like to give you a tip: never use concrete class in the left of assignment, i.e. `ArrayList list = ....` Use `List list = ...`

And avoid using too complicated data structures. 2 dimensional array of lists is too complicated. Create your custom class that encapsulates some functionality and then create collection / array (better 1 dimensional) of objects of your class.

Comment: Okey, thank you for the tip! Could you please explain why you never want to use a concrete class in the left of assignment? With the custom class, I'd still want something that resembles a 2D array. But instead implement it as a 1D array and create some methods like `getRow()` and `getColumn()`?

Comment: @Mattias In most cases you'd like to use the interface instead of a concrete class, since then you could exchange the `ArrayList` with a `LinkedList` if needed. If you need more information on the capabilities (like sorted or not) you might have additional interfaces (consider `Set` vs. `SortedSet`)  but knowing the concrete implementations is rarely useful to the user of a method.

Comment: @AlexR Ah, I see. Thank you for the explanation! I think I have sorted it out now, made a custom class defining each column and a method to insert the result into the correct position. It made everything a lot easier.

Comment: Hi is it possible to make it with generics ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's example for 2x2 matrix with explicit initialization.

```
List<MyClass>[][] matr = new List<MyClass>[][] {
    new List<MyClass> { new ArrayList<MyClass>(), new ArrayList<MyClass>() },
    new List<MyClass> { new ArrayList<MyClass>(), new ArrayList<MyClass>() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex already said, having a 2 dimensional array of lists is quite complicated and easy to get wrong or be used in a wron way.

Since your array should represent a table you might want to create classes for the rows or columns, depending on what is more important.

Alternatively, you could create a class for each cell in the table and manage a 2D array of cells, if you know exactly what number of cells you'd have:

```
class Cell {
  private List<SomeClass> content = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
  ...
}

Cell[][] matrix = new Cell[4][4];  //don't forget to initialize each cell
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static class Grid<T> {

    public interface TFactory<T> {

        T create();
    }
    private T[] data;
    private int d1;
    private int d2;

    public Grid(int d1,
            int d2,
            Class<T> clazz,
            TFactory<T> fac) {
        this.d1 = d1;
        this.d2 = d2;
        data = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, d1 * d2);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = fac.create();
        }
    }

    public T get(int c1,
            int c2) {
        return data[c1 * d2 + c2];
    }
}

public static class ArrayListFactory<X> implements Grid.TFactory<ArrayList<X>> {

    public ArrayList<X> create() {
        return new ArrayList();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RTXException, ParseException {
    // cannot use new new ArrayList<String>[4][4];, because of generic array creation error
    List<String>[][] a2d = new ArrayList[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            a2d[i][j] = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }
    Grid g = new Grid(4, 4, ArrayList.class, new ArrayListFactory<String>());
}
```

Here are two approaches. First is what you asked for, second is encapsulated version (with 2d array transformed into 1d array for easier internal manipulation).

As was said before, you should declare variables as interfaces as much as possible (but not more).
That mean, if all you want to say is, its a List and does not expect anyone to behave differently based on concrete implementation, just use List, not ArrayList as variable type.
But if you use eg. LinkedSet it can be good idea to use LinkedSet as variable type (and as return value of functions), if you want to "promise" that it lists all elements quicly and in insertion order. If you use Set, user of it should not depend on any particular order of iteration.

btw. beware of explicit initialization. It is nice syntax, but it creates anonymous inner class and it can lead to inintended retention of parent class. But if you know what you are doing and that it is not possible to happen (no outside reference) there is nothing wrong with using it.